# How to write Unicode in java without displaying ASCII Code?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to create a program which write only Urdu language characters. I am taking input from JtextArea and I want to show result in that jtextarea, where user will write their message means give input.

The problem is that ASCII code also display with the unicode. I want to disable that ASCII code. What i do now?

```
private void txt2KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
      String f;

      if(KeyEvent.VK_A=='A'){
          f=txt2.getText()+"\u0627"; //Urdu language code "Alif"
      }
      jtextarea.setText(f);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.  Does the string `f` contain ASCII characters in it?  (That is, Unicode characters in the range 0-255?)  If so, where do they come from, and what exactly do you want to do--just remove all the ASCII characters from `f`?  (And do you really mean *all* ASCII characters, or do you want to keep the digits, space character, punctuation, or what?)

Comment: The text which user Write will be convert in Unicode and Save in String f then I just set the text.

Comment: Somewhat ambiguous. You might be looking for the [new String\(byte\[\], String\)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) constructor. That would change the string's encoding to whichever encoding you want.

Comment: How you are setting up your JTextArea would be helpful. Are you changing the locale or text encoding at all for example? (Consider adding the tag unicode to your question).

Comment: Yes, I am trying to change the text directly when user will Write its message.

Comment: Is the problem that `f` contains both `A` and `alif`?  If that's true, then the problem may be that Swing/AWT is adding the text for the key to the `JTextArea`'s text before it calls the listener, so that the `A` will show up in `getText()`, and the answer may be to find out how to disable that behavior in Swing.  If that's not what is happening, please let us know what is in `f`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want the 'A' key to insert a 'ا' instead of an 'A' or 'a'.

Call `evt.consume()` in your `if` statement body to prevent normal handling. See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#consume()).

Comment: Thank you so much Tom Brother. You have solved my Problem.